# pull bandwidth from wireless WAN into local LAN

Tags: networking, bandwidth, wifi

We have a local network (A) of about 50 computers connected via gigabit ethernet. We get a connection to the internet using two broadband connections to a backbone and distribute the bandwidth across the 50 computers using a CISCO 1811 router, but the bandwidth is not enough for everybody.

There is a campus wide wireless network(B) that has very high bandwidth, is there a device or way to setup multiple individual connections to network B and supply the bandwidth to our network A?

Comment: Sorry, you lost me?  Does your wireless network have a separate Internet connection?  If it does why would you want multiple connections to it?  A wireless network isn't like a switched network.  If one connection saturates the link the it saturates the link for everyone.  Unless your second connection is   on a different range of frequencies.

Comment: Yes the wireless network has a separate internet connection. Each device connected to the wireless network has a bandwidth limit of 21Mbps. But you can connect multiple devices to the wireless network so i want to know if i can harness the bandwidth and supply it to my local ethernet based network.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely need more details, perhaps a simple diagram.  But my guess here is that you could use a wireless bridge, attach a switch and some routing rules on your router.